# He who troubles his own house will inherit wind,Proverbs 11:29

Tags: proverbs

Proverbs 11:29  (NASB)

> 29 He who troubles his own house will inherit wind,   And the foolish
>   will be servant to the wisehearted.

What do the two expressions mean?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's that much going on here -- don't create strife in your own household or you will lose everything and end up a broke servant in someone else's household (one whose head of household didn't create strife).

Two keys to unlocking this proverb:

- "House" doesn't refer to a physical structure but *household*. Including extended family.
- To "inherit the wind" is a flowery way of saying "will end up with nothing" or "will be destitute".

So you can read this in a pretty straightforward way:

*He who creates strife in his own household will end up destitute,
and a fool will serve the wise of heart.*

The best exposition I've found is in Hermeneia:

> Verse 29 connects to the preceding verses. The term בַּיִת (“house”)
> can refer to a larger household (see the passage on the woman of valor
> in Prov 31:15, 21). The statement in v. 29a resembles the book of
> Qohelet. The idea that someone inherits (נחל; cf. Jer 5:13) wind
> corresponds to Qoh 1:14, except there all the deeds done “under the
> sun” are described as chasing after wind (רוּחַ, as in Prov 11:29).
> What is meant here is that a person who brings one’s house into
> disarray will have no possessions. The verb עכר qal (“to bring trouble
> upon”) is used already in 11:17 (see also 15:27). The root עכר can
> also mean “to impede, threaten, damage.” When connected to the term
> “household” (בַּיִת), this describes someone who is unjust to one’s
> family and household staff. This aspect is developed further in the
> second half of the verse. Whoever brings trouble on one’s house will
> experience servitude and can only be described as a “fool” (אֱוִיל)—a
> term that in Prov 1:7 refers to someone who despises wisdom and
> instruction and thus understands nothing at all. In contrast, as in
> 10:8, the wise person is described as “one with a wise heart.” As in
> 10:8 and elsewhere, here the heart refers to human understanding.
> Finally, the “miser” from v. 24 comes back into view in v. 29 and is
> threatened here with a dramatic loss of social status. Whoever acts in
> such an irresponsible way will have to learn the hard way, being a
> “servant” (עֶבֶד) to a wise person.

Schipper, B. U. (2019). Proverbs 1–15: A Commentary on the Book of Proverbs 1:1–15:33. (T. Krüger, Ed., S. Germany, Trans.) (p. 411). Minneapolis, MN: Fortress Press.

Comment: Robert: A very good answer  Tks +1 To make your answer more convincing you may include  a scriptural example.: Achan’s wrongdoing ‘brought ostracism upon him,’ and both he and members of his family were stoned to death. (Joshua, chapter 7 : 1-26)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I get from the Hebrew:

> A man who troubles his house will inherit the wind, so a servant who is a fool shall be to the wise of heart.

Details:
[image]

One who is wise of heart is being cautioned here not to hire a fool for a servant, since to do so would be to invite trouble into his household.

To read this as "*the foolish will be servant to the wise-hearted*", makes little sense to me, for what wise person would take a fool for a servant, given what Proverbs has to say about fools:

> <sup>7</sup>The fear of the LORD is the beginning of knowledge: but **fools despise wisdom and instruction**.
>   -- Proverbs 1:7 (KJV)
>
> <sup>35</sup>The wise shall inherit glory: but **shame shall be the promotion of fools**.
>   -- Proverbs 3:35 (KJV)
>
> <sup>6</sup>**Forsake the foolish, and live**; and go in the way of understanding.
>   -- Proverbs 9:6 (KJV)
>
> <sup>1</sup>... A wise son maketh a glad father: but **a foolish son is the heaviness of his mother**.
>   -- Proverbs 10:1 (KJV)
>
> <sup>23</sup>**It is as sport to a fool to do mischief**: but a man of understanding hath wisdom.
>   -- Proverbs 10:23 (KJV)

These are but a small sample of the verses from Proverbs that caution the wise-hearted in regard to foolish men. So, one who is wise of heart should take Proverbs 11:29 as a caution that to hire a servant who is a fool, or retain such a one, would be to bring trouble to his household.

In regard to the meaning of "reap the wind", what Jesus said about the wind/spirit is helpful:

> <sup>8</sup>The wind bloweth where it listeth, and thou hearest the sound thereof, but canst not tell whence it cometh, and whither it goeth: so is every one that is born of the Spirit.
>   -- John 3:8 (KJV)

The context of Jesus' words is not about foolishness, of course, but the nature of wind/spirit, i.e. one can't tell where it is coming from or where it is going. Nor, in the context of Proverbs 11:29, will one be able to determine in what ways the spirit of the foolish servant might bring a household undone.

Comment: Appreciate you  effort. Achan was such a man  who troubled his house and he and his family were stoned to death.(Joshua chapter seven).29a. At 29b, I think it should read,"and the fool will be a servant to the wise. The NET Bible gives excellent explanations on the Footnotes .